# PHPExcel not reading complete number in XML cell

Tags: xml, numbers, format, phpexcel

I must extract data from a third party XML file.
All is fine expect for one column that contains numbers with comma thousand separator,and dot decimal separator.

A number normally represented as "10,000.00" in Excel or OpenOffice, is read by PHPExcel as "10" only.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$inputFileName = "myfile.xml";

/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);

/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

/**  Load $inputFileName to a PHPExcel Object  **/
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$format = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C24')->getNumberFormat()->getFormatCode();
```

Note that format code of the cell is returned as General

Trying to read one of the cell causing problems using:

```
$getValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 24)->getValue();
$getCalculatedValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 24)->getCalculatedValue();
$getFormattedValue = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 24)->getFormattedValue();
```

Always the same value, truncated at the thousand separator: "10" instead of "10,000.00"

Here's the details of the xml file:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ext="http://fxcm.com/xslt/extension" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:of="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">`
```

STYLE DEFINITION

```
`<ss:Style ss:ID="cell_merged_top_odd_integer" ss:Parent="cell_merged_top_odd">
            <ss:NumberFormat ss:Format="#,##0"/>
</ss:Style>`
```

CELL WITH NUMBER CAUSING PROBLEM

```
`<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="cell_merged_top_odd_integer" ss:Index="3">
    <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">10,000.00</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>`
```

MANUAL WAY TO FIX THE PROBLEM
When I save the file from OpenOffice or Excel, the following message pops up [warning message OpenOffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oNCE.png), and PHPExcel finally works as expected, reading "10000".

I cannot act on the third party to change its XML file, nor can I ask the user to re-save the file prior to uploading it on my website.

Any idea of what could possibly go wrong here perhaps?

[warning message OpenOffice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oNCE.png)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Mark Baker, I took the problem at the source, went through the process of PHPExcel in order to str_replace the comma.

In the file Excel2003XML.php (the first library called after identifying the file type), I have modified the public function loadIntoExisting() as follows:

```
public function loadIntoExisting($pFilename, PHPExcel $objPHPExcel)
    {
    ...
    if (isset($cell->Data)) {
       $cellValue = $cellData = $cell->Data;
       //REPLACE THE COMMA
       $cellValue = str_replace(",", "", $cellValue);
    ...
    }
}
```

I am conscious that this will affect all cells containing a comma but so far it fixes the problem.
I'll be looking in replacing the comma only when a specific number format is detected later on.

Meanwhile, thank you Mark for your guidance!

Comment: You can always include an `if` test based on datatype and only execute the str_replace if it's Numeric, which would prevent problems with replacing commas in declared strings

Comment: I'm sorry (in some ways) that I can't do this directly in PHPExcel, but the added overhead of validating and fixing invalid markup shouldn't be the responsibility of the library, which is intended to read valid spreadsheet file formats

Answer (score 0):

Not surprising that PHPExcel reads only `10` when reading a number that actually contains a string value of `10,000.00` The `ss:Data` for a `ss:Type` of `Number` should contain a numeric value, not a formatted string; ie. it should contain an actual numeric value of `10000`, and the `ss:Index` should point to the formatting... Because the XML has said that the value is numeric, then PHPExcel is trying to read it as a numeric, using standard loose-typing rules; and as `,` is not a numeric value, it's only reading the digits up to that non-numeric character

Comment: I've tried to change the dataType of the cell beforehand

Comment: `$cellStr = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 24)->setDataType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);`

Comment: The problem isn't something you can do by modifying the datatype through PHPExcel, it's the Reader that reads the xml; by the time that PHPExcel can see the data, it's already been stored as `10` by the Reader..... how was this file created with the wrong datatype/value for the cell in the first place?

Comment: Basically, you're asking that PHPExcel should read invalid data from the xml file, and make it valid.... the real solution is to fix this at source... the best you can do is modify the Reader to strip commas from any value that is identified as Type number before casting it to a float

Comment: The original XML file is generated automatically by the 3rd party's software; I can hardly change that.